# Client library for Polkadot in python

Tags: polkadot

Like web3.js and Web3.py can be use for ethereum and binance smart chain,I want to ask that which library in python we can use for polkadot?

Comment: Could you select an answer if any one of them answers your question?

Answer (score 4):

Go for [`py-substrate-interface`](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface).

---

BTW, you could find a lot of useful things in the [awesome-substrate](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate).